# How to remove newline between tags?

Tags: c#, .net, xmldocument, xmlnode

Let say i have this code:

```
        XmlNode counsel = doc.CreateElement("COUNSELS");
        XmlNode p = doc.CreateElement("p");
        counsel.AppendChild(p);
        XmlNode b = doc.CreateElement("b");
        p.AppendChild(b);
        b.InnerText = "Counsel:";
```

and it will output:

```
<COUNSELS>
  <p>
    <b>Counsel:</b>
  </p>
</COUNSELS>
```

what can i do to achieve this:

```
<COUNSELS>
  <p><b>Counsel:</b></p>
</COUNSELS>
```

correct me if i made any mistake on writing this post.

Comment: do you think your expected format is more beautiful? it is inconsistent.

Comment: @LeiYang yea i know but it is a part of the requirement for my project.

Comment: hacking the xml serialization classes looks too complicated for me. if i were you, i can consider regex replace. do you like this way?

Comment: @LeiYang sure, ill be glad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the OP comfirms regex replace is acceptable. I can use two simple replaces.

```cs
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

Regex reg1 = new Regex(@"<p>\s+", RegexOptions.Compiled);
Regex reg2 = new Regex(@"\s+</p>", RegexOptions.Compiled);

string xml = @"<COUNSELS>
  <p>
    <b>Counsel:</b>
  </p>
</COUNSELS>";
xml = reg1.Replace(xml, "<p>");
xml = reg2.Replace(xml, "</p>");
Console.WriteLine(xml);
```

*output*

```sh
<COUNSELS>
  <p><b>Counsel:</b></p>
</COUNSELS>
```

You can follow the pattern to replace space around other tags, or use more advanced single time replace, all depend on your actual requirement and skills.

Comment: he might be waiting for some other answer, hacking xml serialziation.

Comment: @FoggyDay i dont have enough reputation for upvoting

Comment: @Mana - have an "upvote" :)  Q: Does that help?>